# Oracle SQL. Spelling out a date (formed out of a number) in Russian

Tags: sql, oracle, date

The initial task is to spell out a number (12- twelve, 123 - one hundred twenty three, etc.)

It's being performed as follows:

```
select to_char(to_date(:number,'j'),'jsp') from dual;
```

Now, has anyone got an idea what to change in this code so that the numbers were spelled out in Russian? Or maybe I should use completely different approach for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with your desired format, according to what I know.

You can read so [Here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650) and [Here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/610361).

This "should" be the way :

```
select to_char( to_date(123,'J'),'Jsp','nls_date_language=Russian') from dual
```

But will **not** work. If you want other formats it will work, i.e :

```
select to_char(sysdate,'Day', 'nls_date_language=Russian') from dual
```

Some people accomplished it using an api to google translate, will will probably work without a problem since those are easy words to translate, or you can implement it yourself. both examples can be found in the above links.

Comment: I fancy the second solution a lot (the french one): http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1407603857650#4232815086519